# Cancel the saving or the update in prePersist

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I would like to cancel the operation if persist after-has test.and i dont know how i tried the redirection goal in vain.

```
/**
 * @param mixed $object
 */
public function prePersist($object)
{
    if (is_null($object->getFile())) {
    }
}
```

any help ?

Comment: AFRAID it's not possible from there, you need to use constraints validation instead http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

Comment: I think that you shoud be able to throw an exception, but nothing less sure...

Comment: thanks @Yonel ! i solved the problem by adding : * @Assert\NotNull()
to the property     private $file;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably a bit late for you. Since I was looking for the same thing though, here's my solution.

It seems not to be possible to do any validation in Sonatas prePersist method.

For a simple NotNull validation like you are doing it I'd add a simple validation constraint to the entity or if the field is not mapped to the form element itself.

If you want to do some extra validation during Sonatas save process, override the `validate` method. This one is called before the `prePersis`/`preUpdate` methods and it allows you to add validation messages.

```
use Sonata\CoreBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;

public function validate(ErrorElement $errorElement, $object)
{
    $errorElement->with('file')->addViolation('Hey, this is a validation message');
}
```

Comment: I have disabled field and this is not working for the disabled field. :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm a late too but if as me you're facing the same issue. Here is my work around with Doctrine

```php
    use ACME\Exceptions\CustomException;

    public function prePersist($object)
    {
        // Do some stuff with your entity $object
        if (//Something) {
            $this->getRequest()->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add(
                'error',
                'Something wrong happens');
     
            throw new CustomException('Something wrong happens');
        }
        
    }

    /** Overwrite create methode to catch custom error */
    public function create($object)
    {
        try {
            $this->em->beginTransaction();
            $res = parent::create($object);
            $this->em->getConnection()->commit();

            return $res;
        } catch (CustomException $e) {
            $this->em->getConnection()->rollBack();

            return null;
        }
    }
```

This way you can validate or do anything you want in `prePersist` (and/or `postPersist`) and cancel creation throwing an exception.

Unfortunately it still display success flash bag but persist anything in your database.